# Add result of multiple sql queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add the result of 3 SQL queries. All 3 queries return integer values.

How can I add the results from the 3 SQL queries into a variable and echo it?
The code:

```
<?php
define('HOST','mywebsite.com');
define('USER','username');
define('PASS','password');
define('DB','imagebase');
$con=mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $val1=$_POST['sval1'];
    $val2=$_POST['sval2'];
    $val3=$_POST['sval3'];
    $sql="select price from images where name='$val1'"; //returns 100
    $sql1="select price from images where name='$val2'"; //returns 100
    $sql2="select price from images where name='$val3'"; //returns 100
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

    $count1=mysqli_num_rows($result1);
    $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

    $count2=mysqli_num_rows($result2);

    if ($count==1) {
        $res1=$count;
    } 
    if ($count1==1) {
        $res2=$count;
    } 
    if ($count2==1) {
        $res3=$count;
    } 

    $final=$res1+$res2+$res3;  //should return 300 but returns 3
    echo $final;

    mysqli_close($con);

} else {
    echo 'Error Updating Price';
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Haven't you already? `$final=$res1+$res2+$res3; echo $final;`

Comment: It's difficult to answer this without seeing the queries.  It might be that you can just construct a query to return the total.

Comment: You can use a single query for this. `SELECT SUM(price) FROM images WHERE name IN (?, ?, ?)`. Also, you're open to SQL injection attacks. Read about PDO - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @ceejayoz but its returning 3 instead of 300

Comment: @Melwin that's because `mysqli_num_rows` returns the number of rows in the query result, not the actual result. So each time you call it, it returns 1. You need to fetch the results from the queries before trying to add them. Or, you could get all three in one query as the other comment suggests. Either way, you'll have to fetch. `mysqli_num_rows` will not do it.

Comment: @Don't Panic Yes..it worked.I had forgot the mysqli_fetch. Thankyou very much

Comment: **WARNING** [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) warns that the code in this question is *vulnerable* to SQL Injection. OWASP project: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**  code in question is VULNERABLE to SQL Injection! Don't do this. Any potentially unsafe values that are included into SQL text *must* be properly escaped. The preferred pattern is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders.

---

To address the specific question that was asked: we would need to `fetch` rows from the resultsets, and accumulate the values returned for price.

It doesn't look like we are concerned with the number of rows that are returned; by each query, so there's not really a reason to call num_rows function.

```
$tot = 0;

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $tot += $row['price'];
}

$result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
while( $row = $result1->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $tot += $row['price'];
}

$result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
while( $row = $result2->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $tot += $row['price'];
}

echo "tot = " . $tot;
```

---

But why that whole rigmarole of running three separate queries? If what we want is a total, we could have MySQL calculate that for us.

Also, the object oriented pattern is much easier than the procedural pattern.

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(i.price) AS tot_price
          FROM images i
         WHERE i.name IN ( ? , ? , ? )';

if( $sth = $con->prepare($sql) ) { 
   $sth->bind_param('sss',$val1,$val2,$val3);
   if( $sth->execute() ) {
       $sth->bind_result($tot_price);
       if( $sth->fetch() ) {
          echo "tot_price = " . $tot_price;
       } else {
         // no row returned 
       }
       $sth->close(); 
   } else {
      // handle error in execute
} else {
   // handle error in prepare
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! I didn't realize you could `fetch_assoc` on mysqli statements. I thought you had to fetch into bound variables. I guess I'm a bit rusty with mysqli.

Comment: @Don'tPanic..  i've probably got it wrong, i should refrain from posting answers including mysqli...  i'm more familiar with PDO.  (Answer edited)

Comment: Yeah, same here. It's so much easier to use.

Comment: I also see in the first code block in my answer, I added oo-style calls mixed in with OP original procedural calls... ACCCKKK.  i need more practice changing gears, switching from PDO to mysqli, and switching from oo-style to procedural style.  But I absolutely refuse (in good conscience) to switch gears into including *any* code that follows a pattern that appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your if statements, you forgot to change `$count` to `$count1` and `$count2` in second and third statements.
Also, are you sure you want to check that `$count, $count1, $count2` are equal to 1?
You may want to check if those variable have falsy value so `if($count)` etc.
After that, you need to initialize  `$res1, $res2, $res3` to 0 before the if statement, otherwise it can occour you get error later when summing `$res` variables that are not initialized due to falsy if statement before.